# rails3 - check_box_tag - how to make a Conditional Disabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Given the following Rails 3 check_box_tag

```
<%= check_box_tag 'XXXXXXX', 'true', true, (@setting.archived == true, :disabled =>  ?  true : false ) %>
```

How do I make the disabled setting conditional on @setting.archived ?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

You've nearly got something that'll work. Try:

```
<%= check_box_tag 'XXXXXXX', 'true', true, :disabled =>  (@setting.archived ?  true : false ) %>
```

remembering that `(test ? a : b)` is a single expression evaluating to `a` if `test` is true, and `b` if it's false.

Answer (score 2):

To shorted [Chowlett's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4721377/282110), you can just do:

```
<%= check_box_tag 'XXXXXXX', 'true', true, :disabled =>  @setting.archived %>
```