# Rails 5: disable checkbox on condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**I'm trying to figure out how to make checkbox disabled on condition?**

This is my piece of code from view:

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:company_ids, @user_companies, :id, :name) do |b| %>
 <div class="col-sm-1">
   <%= b.check_box %>
 </div>
   <%= b.label %><br><br>
<% end %>
```

I need to make it disabled if `@user = current_user`

In [collection_check_boxes docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes) I don't see how to accomplish this. I assume there is some way, but so far no luck of finding one. My naive thinking was maybe condition can be stated somehow in view. [Answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721365/rails3-check-box-tag-how-to-make-a-conditional-disabled) show how to do that with check_box_tag.

I'd be happy for any hint how to solve this. Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you just want to use the HTML disabled attribute, you could do something like this:

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:company_ids, @user_companies, :id, :name) do |b| %>
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <%= b.check_box disabled: @user == current_user  %>
  </div>
  <%= b.label %><br><br>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you. It's almost what I need! I tried it, but now check-boxes are disabled for any user, not just current_user. Any ideas what should be adjusted?

Comment: Is @user always == to current_user for some reason?  maybe add `<% if Rails.env.development? %><pre>is current: <%= @user == current_user %></pre><% end %>` to the template and see what it's getting for that? hm

Comment: Not sure as `current_user` is editing settings for `@user`, for example: `Started GET "/en/users/8/edit"` however my `current_user` ID=2.   Basically I would like not to allow current user to tick out its company accounts so it stays connected. Otherwise it can tick out that for any other user.

Comment: @Iceman Tried, but it does not help as @chad_ assumed for some reason my form takes `@user = current_user`. This is strange as I clearly can see it allows me to edit some other @user settings with my `current_user`. I have to investigate more what's going on with my form.

Comment: @Iceman Seems it was all about Rails 5 version. So far I used `5.1.0.rc1`, but then `<%= b.check_box disabled: @user == current_user  %>`  did not work. I downgrade to `Rails 5.0.2` and now it works just fine.

Comment: @matiss is downgrading Rails the only way to fix this? I'm having the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51046019/collection-check-boxes-disable-checked-checkboxes

Comment: @alisontague At that time it seemed to be the only solution for me. Your link does not open active SO question.

Answer (score 0):

Use bootstrap disabled class or create one with as

```
.disabled{
  pointer-events: none;
   cursor: not-allowed;
 }
```

Now you can use this class to disable the check box.

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:company_ids, @user_companies, :id, :name) do |b| %>
 <div class="col-sm-1">
   <%= b.check_box( class: (@user == current_user) ? "disabled​" : "" ) %>
  </div>
   <%= b.label %><br><br>
 <% end %>
```

You can also use display property to hide element on basis of class of element

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to disable the checkbox, and show the div disable also.

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:company_ids, @user_companies, :id, :name) do |b|%>
 <div class="col-sm-1 <%=(@user == current_user) ? "disabled​" : ""%>">
   <%= b.check_box( onclick:"return false;")) %>
  </div>
   <%= b.label %><br><br>
 <% end %>
```